# Can you safely install high-pressure sodium wall packs indoors?

Tags: electrical, lighting, safety

I really like the appearance of old street lights (the high-pressure sodium kind). To get the same effect indoors, I was thinking of getting an ordinary high-pressure sodium wall pack (like [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lithonia-Lighting-70-Watt-High-Pressure-Sodium-Black-Wall-Pack-Light-OWP-70S-120-P-LP-BZ-M6/202193062), but ideally at a lower wattage), wiring it appropriately, and mounting it to an interior wall of my apartment.

Is there any non-obvious reason why this is a bad idea? Is it a safety risk or a fire hazard to install HPS wall packs like this one indoors? Is whether I use a junction box relevant, and is a GFCI necessary?

Comment: i am not certain about this, but those lights may cause some plastics to age at an accelerated rate, causing plastic to turn yellow and brittle ... like i said, i am not 100% sure, i may have the lights mixed up with another type, but it may be worth checking

Comment: You're thinking mercury vapor, and "unsheilded" mercury vapor at that (I used to use one of those for exposing photo-sensitive printed circuit boards) - those have significant UV output, but the stock bulbs have a UV-Blocking envelope to cut that down. Sodium-vapor is horrifically yellow - LPS are pretty much just the sodium double-yellow line, HPS is strongly that but manages to get a *little bit more* spectral fill-in so it's not JUST sickly yellow. But point a diffraction grating at one and you'll see that it's still very strongly the double-yellow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than *quickly reducing your visitors* (wow, remember when we had visitors?) *to those like-minded individuals who love HPS light,* there's no issue with putting a wet-rated "exterior" fixture indoors, unless the instructions forbid that. Indoors is generally a less extreme environment than outdoors, so a fixture that operates safely outdoors will operate safely indoors.

**Other potential downsides:** I think 35W is about as low as you can go with HPS bulbs that I've seen, and there IS the fact that they take ***5 minutes or more*** to turn all the way on.

If the wall pack is designed to mount to a junction box, you must use one. If the wall-pack design incorporates a junction box you don't need another. You don't need a GFCI on lighting circuits if they are hard-wired unless they are too close to a tub or shower - you do if they are cord-and-plug, or too close to/over a shower or tub.

---

For a *similar* (not the same, though it is the same color temperature) color and faster turn on with lower wattages, there are 2000K LEDs available.

Comment: You use the word "visitor". I, I don't know what that word means... :( - Of course, I knew a guy who ordered anchovies on his pizza so he didn't have to share it. Maybe the OP wants HPS lighting for a similar reason - to keep others out!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I do think the one other trick will be properly securing it to the drywall--unlike in an exterior wall, I may need to use drywall anchors to secure it in place. (Finding a stud probably won't work, since most of these wall packs require two screws spaced a few inches apart horizontally.) Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: One trick for mounting:  Go to a building material recycle centre and get a used kitchen cabinet door.  This is secured to the studs.  The lamp is secured to the door.

Answer (score 2):

**There is no lower wattage**.  70W is about as small as those get!

If you want that look, then use an LED fixture of your choice and install cinematic gels to tune it to the look you want.   Which are sheets of plastic, not actual gel.

They're mostly used to color-correct color temperature, say you have daylight pouring in a window at 5000K versus a desk lamp at 2700K, you filter one or the other so they match.

However, cinematic gels come in every color in the rainbow.  You can do anything you want with them.  Just tell the cinema company you need to balance LEDs of ____K color temperature to resemble high-pressure sodium (Or LPS if you really like your orange).

Another way to get there is to find a fixture you like with a frosted bezel, then tear out the guts and cram it with 12 volt LED strips of RGB or RGBW type, along with a controller.

Comment: +1, IMO this is the best solution.  This is a solved problem in the film industry, because frequently when shooting outdoors at night, you need to make things look like light is coming from a streetlight just off camera, but that light might not actually be there where you need it, or might not be as bright as you need.  So they use standard film lighting, and put color correction gels on them to make them look exactly like HPS light.

Comment: I wouldn't "cram" LED strip into a closed container, anymore. It gets hot and they fail quite quickly. For example, even just 15 in a wine bottle will partially fail in six months. Of course, as they fail, it reduces heat, so some will keep going "forever".